# Forked at a parallel gateway, can task on one path change the priority of task on the other path?

Tags: task, priority-queue

If a workflow diverge into 2 paths with 1 stopping at a user task while on the other path some conditional logic might need to update the said user task's priority... is this possible or maybe i workflow just need a rethink

Comment: I think Business Key is the key to my solution. https://camunda.com/blog/2018/10/business-key/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.